# Copy sharing records

Tags: sharing

New to SFDC. If we use Informatica to copy data out from SFDC into a custom data warehouse, is there a way to copy the "sharing records" that SFDC maintains that determines which user has access to what records/objects? From what I read about the sharing model, some things are implemented using explicit sharing records but others are computed dynamically at run-time. I also see the UserRecordAccess object, will that help here? Is there a way to export this data out of SFDC using Informatica?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Informatica can do a query of any table, so if the running user for the integration can see that table, then it can be exported. Just make sure the running user has View All Data (and possible Modify All Data, though I'm not 100% sure if that will be necessary).